# DMCA counter notice and court action

Tags: dmca

Suppose there are two parties A and B.

A files DMCA against B and the material is taken down. Then B files counter notice against A.
Then google sends notice to A that unless A submits notice that they have filed a court order on the infringing material, then the material will be restored. So then A files a court order and shows proof to google. So as a result, is the material taken down or restored? Or is it dependent upon the outcome of the court action?

Answer (score 3):

If a legal action is filed, the take down order generally remains in force until a court orders otherwise. If a legal action is not filed with the required time frame, the Internet Service Provider (ISP) such as Google is no longer required to honor the take down order. See generally [here](https://copyrightalliance.org/ca_faq_post/dmca-notice-and-takedown-process/) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notice_and_take_down).

Also, an ISP is not required to honor even a valid takedown order. Doing so sacrifices the ISP's statutory immunity from copyright law liability, but that is all.

Comment: Addition: should the suit end with a loss of or dismissal by the suing party, they might be liable for losses incurred by taking down the material as well as lawyer and court fees.